# rebuild jcarousel in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox, jcarousel

I have jcarousel, I create it by  drupal module print it in hidden(diplay:none)element("main-content" it work correctly here), then I create colorbox with that

```
   $('.quicktabs-views-group  .frame-colorbox').colorbox({
        html: function() {
              return $(this).siblings('.main-content').html(); 
               },
        width:'950px',
        rel: 'group_0',
        opacity : 0.8, 
});
```

**but jcarousel not work in colorbox,I know it because of geting `html` and put it in `colorbox`, what is solution,how can I have jcarousel in color box?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/v7g0vy2d/

```
$('#test').colorbox({    
    html: $('.main-content').html(), // get carousel html

    onComplete:function(){   //Callback that fires right after 
                             //loaded content is displayed.   

        initCarusel()        //Calls a function that creates

    }
});

function initCarusel()
{
       $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();  
       ...                  // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I try that but not worked.
tnx for your attention, I do it by create jcarousel completely after load in color box